Trying to make Nginx start with Ubuntu
I have been trying to get my Nginx local multi streaming server working. I have it working sort of, but here's the rub. I have Nginx installed, and I can get it to run and work great when I use the command:
sudo service nginx start

However when I try to make Nginx run on boot automatically using info I found online with the following command...
sudo systemctl enable nginx

...it accepted the command but just flat out refuses to auto start the service on boot.
When I go to run the service manually after boot with...
sudo systemctl start nginx 

or...
service nginx start

...it seemingly starts just fine as confirmed with sudo systemctl service nginx, but it just doesn't want to start with Ubuntu upon boot.
Results of journalctl -xeu nginx.service :


When you boot, run: journalctl -xeu nginx.service It'll show you what's going on

https://ibb.co/ZdcJDDk

@MartinMac run sudo nginx -t and see what it says the error is with your configuration file.  Because it suggests you have an invalid configuration.

yeah but when I run the start commands manually it starts without issue.
ran it, syntax is ok
test is successful
this is after a manual start as soon as the machine boots (I'm running in a vm if that matters)
